# unable to scrape data from the bls website from before 2011 using rvest and blscrapeR

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to scrape the following website

`https://data.bls.gov/timeseries/CUURS49FSA0` using the following code

```
library(rvest)

url <- read_html("https://data.bls.gov/timeseries/CUURS49FSA0")

xpath_node <- '//*[(@id = "table0")]//td | //*[(@id = "table0")]//th'

yr_CPI_pre2018.df <- url %>%
html_nodes(xpath = xpath_node) %>%
html_text() %>% 
matrix(nrow = 16) %>%
t() %>% 
data.frame() 

colnames(yr_CPI_pre2018.df) <- yr_CPI_pre2018.df[1, ]

yr_CPI_pre2018.df <- yr_CPI_pre2018.df %>% 
slice(-1)
```

My code is only able to download 2011 to 2021 but I'd like to get the data from 2000 to 2021

I've also tried using `blscrapeR` but this library will not query this data set from before 2018.

```
month_HI_CPI_post2018.df <- bls_api("CUURS49FSA0", startyear = 2000, endyear = 2000)
```

Comment: I would suggest going to the web page and downloading and reading the Excel. As opposed trying to learn how to change and submit the form.  My advice is spend the time on the analysis and presentation instead of performing the one time down the data from 2000 to 2017 will never change.

Comment: @Dave2e I am developing a program that updates CPI data every month.  This program will be used by multiple researchers in the division.  I guess I just wanted to create a code that was self sufficient as a means to minimize the probability of error (e.g incorrect folder structure etc).  But I agree, no need to waste time on static data.  Thanks!

Comment: I understand that.  My point is the historical data is not changing thus read it once and store it.  Them each month/year read in the changes the and update the dataset.  This would be more efficient than reading all of the data over and over again.